# MFC C++ - MDI tabbed views drop-list menu disappeared

Tags: c++, mfc

I am learning MFC C++ and found a problem with MDI tabbed menu. Even my application is a MDI style but I can not see document list drop-list menu. Please help me! Thanks in advance!

I have tried to change values in `CMDITabInfo` but nothing happens...

```
CMDITabInfo mdiTabParams;
mdiTabParams.m_style = CMFCTabCtrl::STYLE_3D_ONENOTE; // other styles available...
mdiTabParams.m_bActiveTabCloseButton = TRUE;      // set to FALSE to place close button at right of tab area
mdiTabParams.m_bTabIcons = FALSE;    // set to TRUE to enable document icons on MDI taba
mdiTabParams.m_bAutoColor = TRUE;    // set to FALSE to disable auto-coloring of MDI tabs
mdiTabParams.m_bDocumentMenu = TRUE; // enable the document menu at the right edge of the tab area
EnableMDITabbedGroups(TRUE, mdiTabParams);
```

[image]

Comment: The image you show ***is*** the drop-down window menu. Open more child windows and their names will appear in the list.

Comment: Dear Adrian Mole, Thank you very much for your reply! I have opened 10 tabs but the menu still didnt appear. It is so strange that I have changed CMDITabInfo values but nothing update even m_style...

Comment: Have you tried to use CMFCTabCtrl::EnableTabDocumentsMenu ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cmfctabctrl-class?view=msvc-160#enabletabdocumentsmenu

Answer (score 0):

On ending of your `CMainFrame::OnCreate` you can write:

```
EnableMDITabs(TRUE, TRUE, CMFCBaseTabCtrl::LOCATION_TOP, TRUE, 
    CMFCTabCtrl::STYLE_3D_SCROLLED, FALSE, 
    FALSE);

CMFCTabCtrl& MFCTabCtrl = GetMDITabs();
MFCTabCtrl.EnableTabSwap(TRUE);
MFCTabCtrl.EnableTabDocumentsMenu(TRUE);
MFCTabCtrl.EnableAutoColor(FALSE);
```

This ensure you what you need.

Comment: Dear Flaviu2, Thank you very much for your reply! Yes I have this function inside CMainFrame::OnCreate(). But it didnt worked. I have create a new project then everything is fine now.